Get x and y radius of a hexagon no matter the angle
I created a hexagon blur that gives this kind of results:

To make the code a bit cleaner, I created a hexagon class.
I'm now implementing different methods inside.
My constructor look to this for now:
def __init__(self, radius, center_x, center_y, angle=0):
        self._dmin = np.sqrt(3)/2

        self._radius = radius
        self._radius_min = radius * self.dmin
        self._center_x = center_x
        self._center_y = center_y

        self._angle = angle  # Angle in degrees
        self._radian = np.radians(self.angle)

        self._period = 60

I stuck on the methods radiusX and radiusY. This methods should give in output the distance from the center to the border based on the current hexagon center. For radiusX with a y at 0 and radiusY with a x at 0.

I tried different implementations but the more accurate one I got until now is:
def radiusX(self) -> float:
        return self.radius_min + Trigonometry.one2Zero2One(x=self.angle%self.period, period=self.period) * (self.radius - self.radius_min)

    def radiusY(self) -> float:
        return self.radius_min + Trigonometry.zero2One2Zero(x=self.angle%self.period, period=self.period) * (self.radius - self.radius_min)

The methods one2Zero2One() and zero2One2Zero() are implemented like this:
    @staticmethod
    def one2Zero2One(x, period):
        return 0.5 + 0.5 * np.cos(x * np.pi / (period / 2))

    @staticmethod
    def zero2One2Zero(x, period):
        return 0.5 + 0.5 * np.sin(x * np.pi / (period / 2) - 1.58)

They allow you to obtain a value on a bell between 0 and 1.
zero2One2Zero look to this:

In my class, a hexagon with an angle of 0 is in this direction:

I know that my two methods are not good because when I visualise the results with plotly, I directly see that the radius doesn't follow the one2Zero2One and zero2One2Zero curves. In the examples below, above and on the right is have a green point which indicate the end of the x and y radius:







This graphics are obtained with:
h = Hexagon(radius=0.5, center_x=0.5, center_y=0.5, angle=j)
        fig = go.Figure()
        inside = {'x':[], 'y':[]}
        outside = {'x':[], 'y':[]}
        radius = {'x':[h.center_x + h.radiusX(), h.center_y], 'y':[h.center_y, h.center_y + h.radiusY()]}
        print(h.radiusX())
        for i in range(int(10e3)):
            # print(i,'/',int(10e3))
            x, y = random(), random()
            if h.isPointInside(x, y):
                inside['x'].append(x)
                inside['y'].append(y)
            else:
                outside['x'].append(x)
                outside['y'].append(y)

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=inside['x'], y=inside['y'], mode='markers', name='Inside'))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=outside['x'], y=outside['y'], mode='markers', name='Outside'))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=radius['x'], y=radius['y'], mode='markers', name='radius', marker={'size':10}))
        fig.show()

What is the correct equation for getting the radiusX and radiusY based on the current hexagon angle?

Hi, and welcome to SO! Your question has a lot of details and images, but it would be helpful if you could explain the behavior you want for your function. It would be even more awesome if you could provide input-output pairs, showing what you want the functions to produce for hexagons with specific settings.

The output i don't know it and it's the problem.
The goal of radiusX and radiusY is to get the radius on the x and y axe.
We know the radius that is determined when you create the Hexagon.
But when you turn the hexagon, as it's not a circle, the radius on the axe x and y will variate between r and sqrt(3)/2*r. My goal is get in output the actual radius x and y based on the current angle. I tried with a linear variation and this cos and sin one. But none on them keeped me well on the hexagon edge as you can see with all that images. The helpl i am looking for it to find the correct equation.

To be clear, by radius X you mean the largest difference along the x-axis between a point in the hexagon and its center, yes? And the _radius attribute specifies the distance between the center of the hexagon and one of its vertices? I was going to ask whether the angle is clockwise or counter-clockwise, but given the symmetry of the hexagon, it shouldn't matter, right? If it does, perhaps I am misunderstanding the question.

@AlexDuchnowski You are right, i am not clear there. I have update the post.
Radius is the distance from the center to the circle border (or the maximal distance from the center to the hexagon border).
RadiusX is the distance from the center to the hexagon border but with an y at 0 (horizontal).
RadiusY is the distance from the center to the hexagon border but with an x at 0 (vertical).
Yes, when you rotate it, it come back to its initial position (visually) after have turn pi/3 or 60 degrees

Please don't edit an answer into your question. You can post your own answer if you'd like.

It's not an answer, it was a complement to the answer i have accepted

It's still an answer... you can link to the provided answer in yours, and even post yours as community wiki if you want to eschew all rep for it as being supplementary / attributive.

By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow! The [tour] and [ask] are good resources for getting started.

As far as your code goes, you don't need to use anything besides core Python for the geometric computations.
The math module provides the trigonometric and transcendental functions you need:
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, degrees, radians, pi

No need for NumPy:

to convert from degrees to radians, use radians. E.g. radians(360)/(2*pi) == 1.0
to convert from radians to degrees, use degrees. E.g. degrees(2*pi)/360 == 1.0.

The only use for np variants of radians, degrees, sqrt, etc. is to have automatic broadcasting across NumPy arrays. Since you're dealing with scalars, bringing NumPy into the picture only muddies the water. Stick to core Python where possible - it makes the code easier to understand.
NumPy is useful for image manipulations, since it'll be faster than even fairly streamlined Python code. Nevertheless, the specializing compiler in Python 3.13 can already make NumPy unnecessary for some tasks :)

Suppose we have an n-polygon inscribed into a circle of radius r.
Then:
(1) α = 360°/n
From basic trigonometry:
(2) h/r = cos(γ) = cos(α/2), thus h = r cos(α/2)
(3) h/dx = cos(β), thus dx = h/cos(β)
Substituting (2) into (3), we get
(4) dx = r cos(α/2) / cos(β)
Then we substitute (1) into (4), and finally
(5) dx = r cos(180°/n) / cos(β)
You can work out dy similarly.
To investigate such geometric problems, GeoGebra works well. That's what I used to make the illustration above. That's what you should use to make properly labeled illustrations for your question. Help us help you!
Note: It is not possible to select overlapping objects well in GeoGebra - only the "first one" gets selected when you click on overlapping objects. To help selecting a particular object when they overlap (e.g. a short segment overlapping a long segment), switch from "Tools" to "Algebra" and you'll get a list of objects that you can select within the list.


Thank you very much. I just add that you need to be in a period of 180/n2.
angl = self.angle % 60 (60 is 180 / 6 * 2)
As cos(β) continue to increase after 180/n pass, you need to revert it as we want it to diminish now :
180 / n * 2 - angl so 60 - angl for an hexagon.
With the above elements, when we calculate dx = 1cos(180°/ 6) / cos(0) give sqrt(3)/2.
As my hexagon is not into that direction it's r cos(180°/n) / sin(60+β) or r cos(180°/n) / cos(β - 30) as you prefer
